# Finding sum of all quotients

Tags: algorithm, math

Given two numbers M and N. Let qi be integer part of i*N/M. What is the sum of qi's over i from 0 to M-1. O(M) is the obvious method. Can this be done in less time, may be O(1) if there exists some simpler reduced expression?

Comment: You'll get a better response to this question over at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. (This post will make me wish we had math formatting on SO...)

My approach is to write the problem as

```
∑i floor(i*N/M) = ∑i i*N/M - ∑i [i*N/M]
```

where `[]` is the "fractional-part-of" operator (i.e. [1.3] = 0.3, [6] = 0, etc.).

Then, the first half is easy: it's a normal arithmetic sequence sum multiplied by `N/M`, so it sums to `N*(M-1)/2`. The second half is trickier to deal with, but you'll see why it is crucial to separate it from the first half.

Let `k = gcd(N, M)`. Then, let `n = N/k` and `m = M/k`, so the second half is `∑i [i*n/m]`. Crucially, `n` and `m` are now relatively prime. The sum over `i` is from `0` to `M-1 = km-1`. We can split `i` into a multiple of `m` and the remainder, as `i = qm + r`, so that the sum is now

```
∑q ∑r [r*n/m]
```

where `q` sums from `0` to `k-1` and `r` sums from `0` to `m-1`. Now comes the critical step: because `n` and `m` are relatively prime, the sequence `r*n` for `r = 0..m-1` is a *permutation* of `0, 1, 2, 3, ..., m-1` *mod m*. Therefore, the sequence `[r*n/m]` is a *permutation* of `0/m, 1/m, 2/m, ..., (m-1)/m`, and so `∑r [r*n/m] = ∑r r/m = m*(m-1)/2/m = (m-1)/2`. Thus, the entire sum collapses to `k * (m-1)/2 = (km - k) / 2 = (M - k) / 2`.

Finally, we combine the halves: `N*(M-1)/2 - (M-k)/2 = (NM - N - M + k)/2`.

Thus, the desired sum is `(NM - N - M + gcd(N, M))/2`. Calculating the GCD can be done [relatively quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3981010/1204143) using Euclid's algorithm, so this will be fairly fast to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to sum 0N/M + 1N/M + 2N/M + 3N/M ... (M-1)N/M. If so, you have (0+1+2+3...+(M-1))N/M. You can solve that in O(1) because (0+1+2+3+...+(M-1)) is M*(M-1)/2. The M's cancel and you get (M-1)N/2.

Comment: It is quotient or integer part of i*N/M. quotient may have been misleading. I edited.