# Number of recursive calls in this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have the following C code. I wanted to know how many recursive calls are made by this function?

```
int gcd(n,m)
{ 
    if (n%m ==0) return m; 
    n = n%m;
    return gcd(m,n);
}
```

The answer is `O(log n)` . In my view, it should be `O(n)` . Please explain how it is `O(log n)`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think it should be O(n)? Have you tried writing out all calls for a few cases of the function call (to get more intuition into how it works)?

Comment: @Dukeling Ok, sorry, I did not try that out, will do. I have edited the question.

Comment: Please note the number of calls in `gcd` are `log(n)` **on average**. There are some cases when the function makes no recursive calls (for instance if `m` divides `n`).

Comment: The number of call is not equivalent to n, it is equivalent to log(n). It means that if gcd(n,m) does X calls, gcd(n^2,m) will do 2X calls (roughly, but complexity is something you should look into).

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev and @Fabinout Thanks for that. I understand the point you make. However, I am actually having difficulty in computing the answer you see. I don't know how to do that. For example, if I get an algorithm like this - `int DoSomething (int n) 
{
  if (n <= 2)
    return 1;
  else 
    return (DoSomething (floor(sqrt(n))) + n);
}` Then , How will I compute the number of recursive calls. Like, there must be standard of procedures or something like that ...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980416/time-complexity-of-euclids-algorithm

Comment: Yes, there will be at most (5 times the number of digits) calls. It means that if you calculate a number which is a power of the previous one, you'll only have a few more calls to do.