# Time complexity of extended Euclidean Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I know that if implemented recursively the extended euclidean algorithm has time complexity equals to O(n^3). I was wandering if time complexity would differ if this algorithm is implemented like the following.
What is the time complexity of the following implementation of the extended euclidean algorithm?

```
public static BigInteger FirstCoefficientOfBezout(BigInteger a, BigInteger b)
{
    BigInteger x=BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger y =BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger X =BigInteger.ONE ;
    BigInteger Y = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger t;

    while (b !=BigInteger.ZERO)
    {
        BigInteger q = a.divide(b);
        BigInteger r = a.mod(b);

        a = b;
        b = r;

        t = x;
        x = X.subtract(q.multiply(x));
        X = t;

        t = y;
        y = Y.subtract(q.multiply(y));
        Y = t;
    }

    return X;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time complexity of Euclid's Algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980416/time-complexity-of-euclids-algorithm)