# What is the bit complexity of Extended Euclid Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

What is the bit-complexity invloved in calculating the greatest common divisor of two n-bit values x and y using Euclids Extended algorithm i.e. the complexity in terms of n

I observed the following pattern while calculating the GCD using a standard Extended Euclid Algorithm in the worst cases for different bit size.
[image]

The complexity in terms of the magnitude of the two values x and y is close to the value:

[image]

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22112305/7418355)

How do arrive at the theoretical bit-complexity to verify my observations?

Comment: The cited formula does not seem to be correct. Have a look for example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258596/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-euclids-algorithm-upper-bound-lower-bound-and-a Also, the "extended" is irrelevant for the asymptotic complexity. It contributes just a constant factor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope you're fitting to the peaks, since you're looking for worst-case complexity.

Anyway...

If **a** and **b** are **N** bits long, then in the worst case (Fibonacci pairs), the extended Euclidean algorithm will take **O(N)** iterations.

Let **f(N)** be the cost of a single iteration.  Certainly **f(N)** will be at least linear, but still polynomial, and nearly half of the iterations in each case will involve arguments at least **N/2** bits long, so the total complexity will be in **O(N * f(N))**

Now, what exactly **f(N)** is will depend in the particulars of how large-integer operations are implemented in your library.  The division/remainder operation will dominate, although wikipedia says that if you use Newton–Raphson division then the complexity of that is the same as multiplication (although there will certainly be a constant multiplier!).

Multiplication costs **O(N * log N * log log N)** in the limit with the Schönhage–Strassen, and hopefully your library will use that eventually... so when the numbers get *really* big, the extended Euclidean algorithm should take **O(N<sup>2</sup> * log N * log log N)** in the worst case.