# Computing GCD on sorted array

Tags: optimization, priority-queue, greatest-common-divisor

Is it possible to get some optimization on any algorithm used for getting the gcd of numbers in an array if the array is sorted?
Thanks!

Comment: Put some thought into your question. What benefits do you think a sorted array would give you? Tell us what you think the answer to the question is, and why.

Comment: Well if the array is sorted then I know that which numbers are larger than others and finding gcd by euclidean algo might be faster if say ,we compute the difference bw 2 elements and use that info to speed up our algo I was just looking if someone could make some concrete optimizations and not the vague one which I just asserted...correct me if Im wrong!

Comment: But you're asking for the GCD of an array of numbers. If I understand correctly, you have many numbers and you're trying to find the GCD of all of them? That is, the largest number that is a factor of all the numbers in the array.

Comment: Yes,but maybe the choice of order of numbers that we may pickup to find the gcd pairwise untill the end of the array ,affect the time taken to compute the overall gcd of the array.

Comment: I am unsure if this is correct that's why I asked this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let's see. The general method of finding the GCD of an array of numbers is:

```
result = a[0]
for i = 1 to length(a)-1
    result = gcd(result, a[i])
```

So what's the complexity of the gcd algorithm? Well, that's a rather involved question. See, for example, [Time complexity of Euclid's Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980416/time-complexity-of-euclids-algorithm)

If we pretend, as posited in the accepted answer, that the GCD algorithm is constant time (i.e. O(1)), then the complexity of the loop above is O(n). That's a reasonable assumption for numbers that fit into computer registers. And if that's the case then spending O(n log n) time to sort the array would almost certainly be a loser.

But in reality the GCD calculation is linear in the number of digits in the two numbers. If your input data consists of lots of large numbers, it's *possible* that sorting the array first will give you an advantage. The reasoning is that the result of `gcd(a, b)` will by definition give you a number that's no larger than `min(a,b)`. So by getting the GCD of the two smallest numbers first, you limit the number of digits you have to deal with. Whether that limiting will overcome the cost of sorting the array is unclear.

If the numbers are larger than will fit into a computer register (hundreds of digits), then the GCD calculation is more expensive. But then again, so is sorting.

So the answer to your question is that sorting will almost certainly increase the speed of calculating the GCD of an array of numbers, but whether the performance improvement will offset the cost of sorting is unclear.

I think the only way you'll know for sure is to test it with representative data.